# Dynamically appending n objects in a list

Tags: r, list

I am working in R.

I have `n` objects all named `x` followed by a number `j = 1,..., n`.

eg, for `n = 5`:

`x1, x2, x3, x4, x5`

I want to be able to list them all together dynamically depending on the `n` value:

`list(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)`

In other words, I need to write a function that returns a list of those similarly-named objects automatically recognizing at what value of `n` to stop.

I tried this:

```
l <- vector()
for (k in (1:n)){
    if (k != n){
        u <- paste0("x",k, ",")
    } else {
        u <- paste0("x",k)
    }
    l <- append(l,u)
}
```

But obviously returns a list of characters...

Does anyone have an idea of how to do that?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you add your objects to a list when they are created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mget` gets a list of objects from their names. Construct the names using `paste` (vectorized), give it to `mget` (also vectorized) and you have your list:

```
l <- mget(paste0("x", 1:n))
```

I'd suggest trying to use lists from the start, rather than creating a bunch of objects then gathering them into a list. My answer at [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) has examples and discussion about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a function:

```
> x1 <- 1:2
> x2 <- 1:3
> x3 <- 2:5
> 
> make_list <- function(n){
+             l <- list()
+             for(i in 1:n){
+             l[[i]] <- get(paste0('x',i))
+   }
+   l
+ }
> make_list(3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 2 3 4 5

> make_list(1)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

>
```